# How to access the state of a component form another component in react-native?

Tags: android, react-native, redux, state, setstate

I am accessing the location data using the `geolocation API` and storing it inside the state of a component called `Location.js`, but I want to access the state from a different independent component say `Slider.js`. What is the simplest and fastest way to access the state? I am a `beginner`. Any help will be appreciated. ie, How to make a state "global" in some sense because I have some other components that want to access the state of `Location` apart from `Slider`. 
There are 10 components which would use the `location state` of `Location.js`, then I would have to perform a `POST` operation using the location data and some data from `Slider` also.

I did some research -

- Some are suggesting to send the state data via props, but I never use the `Slider` component inside the `Location` component. If this can be done, please elaborate.
- Somewhere I found about `redux`, how can it be helpful? And how do I decide I really need it? If yes, can anyone explain briefly how?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The question you are asking is not specific to React Native, but it could be asked about a regular web app written with ReactJS (I say this because it is often easier to find tutorials, etc. in the bigger community of ReactJS)

That being said you have two options:

1. Since your components are separate, you could consider creating a wrapper component, often called a Higher Order Component (HOC), which will encompass both of those components. You should have the geolocation call present in the HOC component and send it down via `props` to any child component that needs it.
2. Use a state management tool - Redux is the most popular state management tool in the React world, but it is not the only one. Another very popular one is MobX. You can think of state management tools like umbrellas that cover your entire application. You can access state stored in Redux in any component, no matter what the parent-child structure is of your application. Redux is considered to have a complex bootstrap, if you do decide to try it out I highly recommend going through this free course on Egghead.io: https://egghead.io/courses/getting-started-with-redux This course was created by Dan Abramov, the actual creator of Redux :)

I hope this helps ;)

Comment: Thank you. My app is of moderate size. Do you think adding `redux` will be unnecessary extra workload or it would be beneficial? As I am on a time crunch so I will have to learn `redux` first... so if any other way is there?

Comment: If you're on a time crunch I'd say to try and build an HOC, if there is a logical way for your components to have a common parent placed not too far from where they are actually used.
But whenever you get a little bit more time I'd recommend learning Redux. Once you add Redux you don't need to refactor your app, just add it bit by bit whenever/wherever possible.

Comment: Can you direct me to some resources for HOC?

Comment: You could read this article in the official ReactJS docs: 
https://reactjs.org/docs/higher-order-components.html#use-hocs-for-cross-cutting-concerns

or you can write a regular component that will serve as the parent of Location.js and Slider.js and pass the necessary props.

Answer (score 0):

Hello for my opinion is not use Redux and other state management library for small and medium scale application development.

- Redux is use for build large scale application for small and medium scale it not necessary.
- For accessing data of location you can set it to service file and access this data to anywhere.

Comment: I  have hand on experience i have used in one in project.

Answer (score 0):

Often times, Redux is overkill and has a steep learning curve.  You can take a look at [XSM](https://github.com/peterluhub/xsm).  It is very easy to pick up and does not get in the way.  Will meet your needs of data sharing crossing components and more.